# Потеря памяти при переходах между контроллерами и проблема с нотификейшн от firebase в убитом проложении(не запущеном)

Tags: firebase, swift3, утечка-памяти

кто может обяснить или где по русски понятно почитать о том как правильно переходить между контроллерами(без UINavigationViewController)

в приложении использую сеги(e.g.Push и Present modal)

такая же картина с памятю когда приходит пуш с другими данными 
( переход на ActiveInfoVC) и если обратно то память не падает

и если несколько раз все повторить то приложение просто падает

как правильно сделать переходы и как убивать контроллер с памяти при его закрытии(знаю что в andriod есть метод - Finish())
что есть подобное в 
swift?
dismiss не всегда срабатывает

вот код с AppDrlegate для ловли PushNotification

и почему-то работает только когда приложение запущено или в бекграунде, когда убито - ничего не приходит хотя сервер пишет 200 OK

[image: вот код с AppDrlegate для PushNotification]
[image: весь сториборд]
[image: memory]

такая же картина с памятю когда приходит пуш с другими данными 
( переход на ActiveInfoVC) и если обратно то память не падает

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    //по тапу з пуша

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
    print("по тапу с пуша==================", userInfo["type"]!)


    if userInfo["type"]! as! String == "add_manager" {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SearchSB", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FindOrderVC") as! FindOrderVC

        vc.name = userInfo["manager_name"]! as! String
        vc.phone = userInfo["manager_phone"]! as! String
        vc.photo = userInfo["manager_photo"]! as! String
        window?.rootViewController = vc
        completionHandler()

    } else if userInfo["type"]! as! String == "new_shipment_request" {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SearchSB", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ActiveInfoVC") as! ActiveInfoVC
        vc.orderId = userInfo["id"]! as! String
        vc.contentType = userInfo["type"]! as! String
        window?.rootViewController = vc
        completionHandler()
    }
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print(userInfo)
    print("1 РАЗ==================", userInfo["type"]!)

            switch application.applicationState {

            case .inactive:
                print("Inactive")
                //  NEVER CALL HERE

                //Show the view with the content of the push
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
                return

            case .background:
                print("Background")
                //Refresh the local model
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
                return

            case .active:
                print("Active")
                //Show an in-app banner
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
                return
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно поздно, но:

Для замены контроллера добавьте к своему

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SearchSB", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FindOrderVC") as! FindOrderVC
...
```

такую замену контроллера:

```
let currentController = window!.rootViewController
for subview in window!.subviews {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
window!.rootViewController = vc
currentController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
    currentController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
})
```

Для решения проблемы в сториборде нужно либо избавиться от такой запутанности, либо организовать переходы программно и правильно описать какие должны уничтожаться, либо смотреть что где куда переходит и правильно уничтожать.